# Image not refreshing (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So basically I'm trying to create a Discord bot that when you type "!cat" the Discord bot sends an image of a random cat inside of an embed but every time I use the command the image stays the same.... I tried to put the embed variable inside of the function so it refreshes every time someone says "!cat" but it didn't work..... this is the code that I'm using:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});





client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
    if (message.content === "!cat") {
     

        
        const catEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("MEOW!")
        .setImage("http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/400")
        .setThumbnail("http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/400")
        message.channel.send(catEmbed)
    }
});



client.login('NOT GONNA TELL MY TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a caching issue. Try to append some random character as a query string to your URL. Something like this should work:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!cat') {
    // generate a random string
    const rand = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    const catEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('MEOW!')
      // append it as a query string
      .setImage(`http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/400?${rand}`)
      .setThumbnail(`http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/400?${rand}`);
    message.channel.send(catEmbed);
  }
});
```